# How do I disable the mini-map in SteamWorld Dig 2?

Tags: steamworld-dig-2

For an extra challenge, I want to try playing through SteamWorld Dig 2 without using the mini-map you receive from Fen. I found an option to disable map markers from the cog mods menu, but I couldn’t find a way to fully disable the mini-map.

How can I disable the mini-map in SteamWorld Dig 2?